# Characterisation of functions $f$ such that their composition $f\circ g$ with an integrable function $g$ is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

It's well-known that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable (we are speaking in the sense of Riemann here) then $f\circ g$ is also integrable on $[a,b]$. There are counterexamples to this conclusion when we allow $f$ to simply be Riemann integrable and interestingly according to [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20045/about-the-riemann-integrability-of-composite-functions) there are counterexamples when $g$ is made continuous, while $f$ is integrable.

My question is this: **is there a nice or known characterisation of which $f$, when composed with an integrable function like $g$, lead to $f\circ g$ being integrable?**

I am familiar with basic topology, analysis and very little measure theory (e.g. I understand the statement of Lebesgue's criterion for integrability) so preferably answers should be phrased roughly at that level. On the other hand, there might be no simple characterisation at all but I'm willing to accept a reference if this has been discussed but perhaps requires a lengthy discussion.